# Apache ODE example

Tags: bpel, apache-ode

Any good apache ODE example available?

I am trying to evaluate Apache ODE for an project. Please provide any references for learning
Apache ODE through samples/tutorials/guide.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/cours/WebServices/TP_BPEL/helloworld.html        looks good. But need more info if anybody has..

Answer (score 2):

You can try the examples shipped with ODE. Also, http://ode.apache.org/resource-services.html provides a list of tutorials that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Indus framework which makes it easy to use Apache ODE.

"Indus is a build system that integrates Apache ODE and brings together various
SOA components. It  has a maven plugin that wraps the bpelc compiler - allowing 
you to compile bpel files prior to their deployment. Furthermore, it creates a 
process sub-directory that contains all the necessary artifacts for the 
process's deployment (including deploy.xml - which is auto generated).

Additionally, all the dependent jars are placed a lib sub-directory and may be 
deployed to ODE's WEB-INF/lib."

https://github.com/sarithi/indus/blob/master/examples/workflow/HelloWorldWorkflowService/mainline/src/main/process/SayHello.bpel